# webpack fails to compile JSX

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

This is the error message that I get (I removed part of the file path for security reasons):

```
ERROR in ./react-components/MyComponent.js
Module parse failed: /home/vagrant/src/***/react-
components/MyComponent.js Unexpected token (6:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {
|     return (
|       <div>
|         <p>FooBar: {this.props.fooBar}</p>
|         <p>Baz: {this.props.baz}</p>
 @ ./client/app/app.module.js 52:19-64
 @ ./client/app/index.js
```

Right now, all I'm trying to do is to just allow a React component to live inside an Angular 1.X project. This is what the webpack config looks like:

`webpack.make.js`:

```
config.module = {
    rules: [{
        // JS LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
        // Transpile .js files using babel-loader
        // Compiles ES6 and ES7 into ES5 code
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [{
            loader : 'babel-loader',
            options : {
                shouldPrintComment(commentContents) {
                    // keep `/*@ngInject*/`
                    return /@ngInject/.test(commentContents);
                },
                plugins : TEST ?
                  [[ 'istanbul', { 'exclude' : [ '**/*.spec.js'] }]]
                  : [],
                presets : ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
            }
        }],
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/')
        ]
    },{
        // ASSET LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader
        // Copy png, jpg, jpeg, gif, svg, woff, woff2, ttf, eot files to output
        // Rename the file using the asset hash
        // Pass along the updated reference to your code
        // You can add here any file extension you want to get copied to your output
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)([\?]?.*)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    }, {

        // HTML LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
        // Allow loading html through js
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
    }, {
        // CSS LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader
        // Allow loading css through js
        //
        // Reference: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader
        // Postprocess your css with PostCSS plugins
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: !TEST
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Extract css files in production builds
            //
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/style-loader
            // Use style-loader in development for hot-loading
            ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        // PostCSS
                        // Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
                        // Add vendor prefixes to your css
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options : {
                            plugins : [
                                autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']})
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/null-loader
            // Skip loading css in test mode
            : 'null-loader'
    }, {
        // SASS LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        loader : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
                'css-loader',
                {
                    // PostCSS
                    // Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
                    // Add vendor prefixes to your css
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options : {
                        plugins : [
                            autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']})
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader : 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        outputStyle: 'compressed',
                        precision: 10,
                        sourceComments: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }),
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app/app.scss')
        ]


    }, {
        // Imports Loader
        // This allows the CodeMirror json linter to find jsonlint, which it expects to be global
        test: require.resolve('codemirror/addon/lint/json-lint'),
        use: 'imports-loader?jsonlint=jsonlint-mod'
    }
    ]
};
```

And here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-3", "stage-0"]
}
```

I've tried both `stage-3` and `stage-0`, but I still get the same error. I made sure to install `babel-preset-react` via npm. There's nothing wrong with the JSX in the JS file, as it's a simple React component that's used as example code from a repository that I'm using. I've gotten to a point where I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: What does the react component look like?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `path.resolve(__dirname, 'react-components')` in the `includes` object, where the JS file in question resides.